# Processing gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer function runs with no results

Tags: pyqgis

Processing **gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer** function is used in PyQGIS and it runs, but no results were obtained. Code is below:

```
import processing

mask = "C:/Users/Siddarth/Desktop/Kamalesh/kamalesh/New folder/Mask/Mask1.shp"
input = "C:/Users/Siddarth/Desktop/Kamalesh/kamalesh/New folder/input/dist2faults2.tif" 
output = "C:/Users/Siddarth/Desktop/Kamalesh/kamalesh/New folder/output/result.tiff"

processing.runalg('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer', 
                   input, 
                   mask, 
                   "", 
                   False,
                   False,
                   False,
                   0, 
                   0, 
                   1, 
                   1, 
                   1, 
                   False, 
                   0, 
                   False, 
                   "", 
                   output)
```

Are used parameters correct?

Comment: After taking the [Tour] please review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for some advice on how to structure questions.  Here the body of your question is almost totally code with no explanation.  The question body should contain everything needed to understand what you are asking.

Comment: i have a raster and a polygon with some holes in it
how i can clip that raster with that polygon?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133084)

Answer (score 4):

When I used your code with your parameters, I got the same result: No raster. For this reason, I modified the code to:

```
import processing

mask = processing.getObjectFromName('polygon2')
input = processing.getObjectFromName('utah_demUTM2')

path = processing.runalg('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer', 
                         input,    #INPUT <ParameterRaster>
                         mask,     #MASK <ParameterVector>
                         "0",       #NO_DATA <ParameterString>
                         False,    #ALPHA_BAND <ParameterBoolean>
                         True,     #CROP_TO_CUTLINE <ParameterBoolean>
                         True,     #KEEP_RESOLUTION <ParameterBoolean>
                         5,        #RTYPE <ParameterSelection>
                         0,        #COMPRESS <ParameterSelection>
                         1,        #JPEGCOMPRESSION <ParameterNumber>
                         1,        #ZLEVEL <ParameterNumber>
                         1,        #PREDICTOR <ParameterNumber>
                         False,    #TILED <ParameterBoolean>
                         0,        #BIGTIFF <ParameterSelection>
                         False,    #TFW <ParameterBoolean>
                         "",       #EXTRA <ParameterString>
                         None)     #OUTPUT <OutputRaster>

clipped = QgsRasterLayer(path['OUTPUT'],
                         'clipped')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(clipped)
```

and I tried it out with next situation:

[image]

After running it at the Python Console of QGIS, I got:

[image]

It worked.